# "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (React.js)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" error. I've been looking at some of the examples provided in similar questions people have posted, but still no luck. Any guesses

Background: I'm on a 3-person team that is developing an app that allows users to see where everyone in a group is on a map. My role in particular is to try to get incorporate a chat interface. I've decided to go with socket.io.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
  // import Chat from "./Chat";
  // import logo from './logo.svg';
  import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';
  import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
  import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";


  import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps- 
  react';

  import './App.css';
  class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        sidebarOpen: true
      };
      this.onSetSidebarOpen = this.onSetSidebarOpen.bind(this);
    }

    onSetSidebarOpen(open) {
      this.setState({ sidebarOpen: open });
    }
    render() {
      const responseFacebook = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }

      const responseGoogle = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }


      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Sidebar
            sidebar={<b>
              <div
                style={{ padding: 40 }}>
                <br />
                <FacebookLogin
                  appId=""
                  fields="name,email,picture"
                  callback={responseFacebook}
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <GoogleLogin
                clientId=""
                buttonText="Login with Google"
                onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                onFailure={responseGoogle}
              />
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" data- 
 toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                My Groups <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-right">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />
            <hr />

            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">
                Current Group <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-right">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-3x" style={{ marginRight: 5, marginTop: 10 }}></i>
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-3x" style={{ marginRight: 5, marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 5 }}></i>
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-3x" style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 10 }}></i>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div className="messages">
              {this.state.messages.map(message => {
                return (
                  <div>{message.author}: {message.message}</div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
            {/* <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button style={{marginBottom: 10}} type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Chat <i class="far fa-comment-alt" style={{marginLeft: 5}}></i></button>

                  <textarea style={{padding: 10}} class="form-control" 
  id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </form> */}
            </b>}
            open={this.state.sidebarOpen}
            onSetOpen={this.onSetSidebarOpen}
            styles={{ sidebar: { background: "white" } }}
          >
            <button onClick={() => this.onSetSidebarOpen(true)}>
             Open sidebar
          </button>
          </Sidebar>
         <br />
          <br />
          <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}>

            <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
              name={'Current location'} />

            <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>

            </InfoWindow>
          </Map>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }



  export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`
  })(App)
```

Comment: where you have defined `messages`? either define `messages: []` in state or use it like this `(this.state.messages || []).map(.....)`

Answer (score 2):

This would likely mean that the state is not being populated with a value at the key of `messages`.

You are trying to map over the value of `this.state.messages` but that doesn't seem to be set.

```
              {this.state.messages.map(message => {
```

If `this.state.messages` is undefined then you will not be able to run `.map` on it (`.map` being an Array specific function).

You're going to want to check your code to ensure you are setting the `messages` to state correctly before trying to map over it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code does not have

```
this.setState({messages:[{ // set a state to populate values in JSX

 author:"author1" // populate values based on your Queries

}]}) // An object inside Array which provides .map() function (every array has .map() inbuilt function)
```

Whenever You see **Undefined** in Javascript the underlying **this.state.messages** does not have any values as it causes **Undefined** in **.map()** function